# Fix React Leaflet TileLayerOffline from leaflet.offline

Tags: caching, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am struggling with saving a map with leaflet.offline. I want to use it with React but I use the  component like this:

```
function Map() {
    return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <MapContainer
        center={[0, -105]}
        zoom={3}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        zoomControl={false}
        maxBounds={L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(-79, -211), L.latLng(81, 209))}
      >
        <LayersControl collapsed={false}>
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="Azibor Map">
            <TileLayer url="http://127.8.8.8:8080/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"
              minZoom={2} maxZoom={7} continuousWorld={false} noWrap={true} keepBuffer={100}/>
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

I want to replace the TileLayer with TileLayerOffline that I've found in the leaflet.offline library:

```
export declare class TileLayerOffline extends TileLayer {
_url: string;
    createTile(coords: Coords, done: DoneCallback): HTMLElement;
    setDataUrl(coords: {
        x: number;
        y: number;
        z: number;
    }): Promise<string>;
    /**
     * get key to use for storage
     * @private
     * @param  {string} url url used to load tile
     * @return {string} unique identifier.
     */
    _getStorageKey(coords: {
        x: number;
        y: number;
        z: number;
    }): string;
    getTileUrls(bounds: Bounds, zoom: number): TileInfo[];
}
```

Although I get an error in the console:
"Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

I've tried to use _url and all of these things but I assume it is not about the string value which is "localhost..."

Is it possible to use the  in a  if not, how can I use L.tileLayer.offline in a

Thanks a lot.